# Witches not spawning as they should

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have 2 witch huts that are close to each other and I have made them into 2 witch farms.

I have cleared out all caves within 128+ blocks of each witch hut.

I have built an afk spot in the middle of the two witch farms which is exactly 126 blocks away from the furtherest corner of each witch farm. However the witches are not spawning when I afk. When I move closer to about +- 60 - 90 blocks of each farm, the witches spawn in large amounts.

As far as I know they should spawn as long as a player is between 24 - 128 blocks away.

I have tried different y levels or different XYZ levels, but nothing. Only one or two spawn sometimes.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Do the witches fall below the witch farms to be killed?

Comment: @FabianRöling no, I transport them upward towards me.

Comment: Is your Y-level 126 higher than the lowest point of the witch farm or did you take the total distance into account (with Pythagorean formula)?

Comment: @FabianRöling I used a formula for total distance... https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/minecraft-tools/1265013-block-distance-calculator

Comment: You don't need any Minecraft specific tools, it's just `sqrt((x1-x2)²+(y1-y2)²+(z1-z2)²)`. But yes, I assume that tool gives you correct information. Hm, then maybe you're too close to the limit and something is unprecise or so. Can you maybe try moving 10 blocks down and see if it improves your rates?

Comment: @FabianRöling thanks, I will test tonight... I also think it might be something like that.